# Is possible to camp in a tent in Iceland in April?

Tags: camping, winter, iceland

I've seen that most camping sites are closed in April, but some are open. I'm wondering if this is because the lack of tourists or because the weather is too bad (snow, wind, etc) to camp in winter. Of course when I say "camp" I'm talking about camp in a tent, not in a vehicle with autonomous heater and hot shower :)

Is too cold to be confortable? People use to camp in April or nobody camps until June?

Comment: What's your threshold for cold like, and what type of gear do you have (in particular sleeping bag)?  I know people that are happy camp down to several degrees below zero C, whilst others won't even consider it if it's in the single digits Celsius.

Comment: Ok, I have good winter camping gear, alpinism like. But my question is about if "people do it" or not. It is, if we go and camp in April, we are going to be alone in the campsite? (not including people on campervans or RV, of course).

Comment: Since wild camping is normally allowed on Iceland, it should not matter if you find an open camp site or not. If you find the weather too cold or bad for sleeping in tent is highly subjective and impossible for any of us to answer.

Comment: Obviously @Tor-EinarJarnbjo, nobody can say if I will be confortable or not. But, it's possible (and that's my question) to know if there's common to camp in Iceland in winter. If this is very rare it will make us think that this is not a good idea, while if this not so rare it could make us think that this could be done and is not a crazy idea. I'm asking about the "normal" behaivour, what people tend to do, not what I should do :)

Comment: See also [Outdoors.SE].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

April in Iceland can be quite cold. It can snow, even in early May. So camping in April is out of the ordinary. Consequently most camping sites do not open until May.

That said, some sites are open in April so it is possible, just be prepared for the possibility of freezing temperatures.

Comment: But is common to see people in these campings in tents or only in motorhomes?